# Getting the number of login attempts in the GET or while rendering the view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I am developing a web application using Laravel. What I am trying to do now is I am trying to get the number of login attempts in the GET or render view. I can get the number of login attempt in the post request (validateLogin method) of LoginController as follow.

```
$this->limiter()->attempts($this->throttleKey($request))
```

The thing is that the validateLogin method takes one parameter, Request $request. What I like to do is that I like to get the number of failed login attempts or number of attempts in the showLoginForm method of LoginController. I am overriding the showLoginForm method. I tried this.

```
$this->limiter()->attempts($this->throttleKey(request()))
```

But it always returns zero. So how can I get the number of login attempts in the GET or showLoginForm method of the LoginController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When login fails, increment the number, when login was successful, clear the attempts. This can be done using sessions. With sessions, you can use it in blade files and in your controllers.

In your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` file:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $attempts = session()->get('login.attempts', 0); // get attempts, default: 0
    session()->put('login.attempts', $attempts + 1); // increase attempts

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
}

/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    session()->forget('login.attempts'); // clear attempts
}
```

Then in your views or controllers you can just get the number from session:

```php
{{ session()->get('login.attempts', 0) }}
```

Comment: Just note that the `ThrottlesLogins` trait counts the number of login attempts for a given email address whereas this would count the login attempts for the session, so you might get some inconsistencies. For example, the `login.attempts` value might be be higher than your `maxAttempts` value.

Answer (score 1):

When we have a look at the [`throttleKey` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php#L87), we see that it creates a key out of the [email address](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L146) the user used tried to log in with and the IP address of the user. The IP address should already be in the `$request` object if you add it as a parameter to the `showLoginForm` method, but the email address wouldn't be there. You could add it using the [`old` helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-old).

```
public function showLoginForm(Request $request)
{

    $request->merge(['email' => old('email')]);

    Log::info($this->limiter()->attempts($this->throttleKey($request)));

    return view('auth.login');
}
```

**Edit**:
Another way to do this would be to overwrite the [`sendFailedLoginResponse`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L132) method and add the number attempts to the error bag. For example, in your `LoginController`:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        'attempts' => $this->limiter()->attempts($this->throttleKey($request)),
    ]);
}
```

Then you could get the number of attempts in your template with `<strong>{{ $errors->first('attempts') }}</strong>`